# CSS height of text line

Tags: css

I wanted to know what are the parameters that dictate the behavior shown in the image below; Before the text there is space as highlighted by the inspector and after the text "overflow" the h1 height.

[image]

Comment: the line-height ?

Comment: why? it is setted to 1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `line-height: 42px` is what dictates the height shown on the element.

As for the slight overflow, this could either be caused by the font-size being larger than the line-height, or due to the font-family you are using.

I would suggest either reducing the font-size slightly, reducing the line-height, or changing the font-family you are using.

Just as an example, the `font-family: fantasy` will fit the container correctly using the same parameters you have.

Here is a working example of this:

```css
h1,
h2 {
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

h2 {
  font-family: fantasy;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <hr class="spacer spacer-10">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
</main>
```

As for gaps between the top of the container and the top of the text, this can be reduced by altering the line-height of the text and the height of the container.

Comment: yes but I set it to 1.. why text takes this behavior? text doesn't fit the h1 height..

Comment: ```<main class="container">

      <hr class="spacer spacer-10">

      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

</main>```

Comment: `font-size: 42px;`, `line-height: 42px;` it happens if I set `font-family: Arial` too..

Comment: From what I know, the only way to fix this would be to decrease the font-size, the line-height or change the font you are using to a slightly smaller one. Other than that I don't believe there is a way to avoid this. I may be wrong though.

Comment: I've added a code snippet above to show how different font-family's can affect the height.

Comment: thank you Daniel for your answer.. this is not a great question but it is just to improve our knowledge.. with your code I can still see few pixels above the text.. :)

Comment: If you want to completely remove the pixels above the text, you would need to reduce the height and line-height.

Answer (score 0):

The `line-height` param indicates the height of a line. If your `font-size` is larger you might have some `overflow`, but by default I think the `overflow` settings is set to `visible` so the text overflow is visible, if nothing else blocks it.

Comment: I understand this but I would expect the text to take over the whole line-height... why it takes this different behavior?

Comment: `font-size: 42px;` `line-height: 42px;` same 'height' but overflow still visible..

Comment: If you really want the exact explanation, you could read the specs: [line-height](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height)